# How do I know which JavaScript methods suit with which HTML-elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to understand which type of JavaScript functions/commands I need to use on which type of HTML-elements to make the intended action (say, print a value on that specific element).

For example, I have now faced the problem of having several different ways to implement the given value to the specific element in the HTML-page, but there is next to no explanations why it works on specific elements.

However, googling about this give me more information about frameworks and alternative workarounds rather how to do it with PLAIN JavaScript, which is what I am looking for.

Comment: Do you mean for example a div uses innerHTML for setting it's contents and a input uses value and a checkbox is a whole different story? Are you asking how you can standardize this ?

Comment: Looks like a perfect question.

Comment: Kind of, but more intricated, say which methods are more <span>-friendly and which more <div>-friendly. That's been the noodle scratcher despite I think I understand the difference between <span> and <div> in HTML, but not how JavaScript, for example, handles these differently.